# Find file location of running process using commandprompt

Tags: process, cmd

I'm hosting gameservers and I'm using SSH to restart servers. In order to check if the required server is online, I use `tasklist /FI "IMAGENAME eq srcds.exe" /V /FO LIST`. However, this doesn't give me really detailed information.

Is there any way to get a list of processes with a given name, and more detailed information such as startup parameters, or port / IP bindings, so I can identify the servers by port + IP or startup parameters?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try WMI. Querying the [Win32_Process](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa394372) class should provide you with the information you're looking for, e.g.

```
wmic process get Caption,CommandLine,ProcessId /format:list
```

Comment: +1, but the CommandLine is not guaranteed to be correct. The application is free to alter the value that appears there.

Comment: But is it possible to only list srcds.exe?

Comment: Nevermind, I found it.  `wmic process where name="srcds.exe" get Caption,CommandLine,ProcessID`